# glMapBufferRange error "Buffer must be bound and not mapped" while trying to implement VAOs

Tags: c++, opengl, vao

So the trouble is that I to write to the buffer:

```
void* dst = glMapBufferRange(target, offset, size, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT | GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT);
```

which does work fine for the first call, but not the second, and I'm not sure exactly why that's the case.

Out of the possible causes:

- GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated by glMapBufferRange if zero is bound to target.
- GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if offset or length is negative, if offset+length is greater than the value of GL_BUFFER_SIZE for the buffer object, or if access has any bits set other than those defined above.
- length is zero.
- The buffer object is already in a mapped state.
- Neither GL_MAP_READ_BIT nor GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT is set.
- GL_MAP_READ_BIT is set and any of GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_RANGE_BIT, GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT or GL_MAP_UNSYNCHRONIZED_BIT is set.
- GL_MAP_FLUSH_EXPLICIT_BIT is set and GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT is not set.
- Any of GL_MAP_READ_BIT, GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT, GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT, or GL_MAP_COHERENT_BIT are set, but the same bit is not included in the buffer's storage flags.

...the only one that I'm not sure how to verify/fix would be "The buffer object is already in a mapped state". Would that possibly be related to the error I'm seeing?

In case it was, I read about GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT, but we're targeting 4.2 and glBufferStorage requires 4.4, so I'm not sure how else I could remedy the situation in that case.

Unfortunately I can't post all the code involved without modifying a ton of stuff, but the basic setup I have is to create a VAO for each newly-created GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, and whenever the buffer would have been bound (code without VAOs), I instead bind the VAO.

The VAO that's bound is for a buffer that we've dubbed "rolling VBO", as it's used as a sort-of catch all for all of our text and other misc. rendering. Perhaps it's because it's used for a lot of dissimilar things...but I'm not sure how to pinpoint what it would be exactly.

If any code piece or other information would help please let me know, I'm not sure what exactly would be needed for this issue. Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: What happens on the second call? Do you get one of the error codes? Do you unmap the buffer after writing to it?

Comment: what is the target you pass? also do you unmap the buffer afterwards?

Comment: @BDL The second call gives the error in the post title: "buffer must be bound and not mapped". Yeah, the buffer is unmapped.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yeah, it's unmapped immediately after copying. The target is GL_ARRAY_BUFFER.

Comment: You can check whether it is mapped with  `glGetBufferParameteriv(target, GL_BUFFER_MAPPED, &res);` and http://docs.gl/gl4/glGetBufferPointerv

Comment: @ratchetfreak Ah, so that call throws a "GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated. Buffer must be bound." So that must be the issue, somehow the buffer is getting unbound prior to that call?